# White rectangles appear when adding moviclips to the stage

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, dynamic

I'm working on a pretty complex AS3 project. I have a few "screens" (which are just movieClips I add to the stage), which contain several .PNG images. These images are loaded dynamically from files on my server. They display correctly, but sometimes (and only in Chrome, as far as I can see) I also have white rectangles appearing beside these images, or where they used to be after I remove them from the stage.
I have been trying to solve this for a few days now, and still have no idea why this is happening...

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

After many frustrating tests, I have changed the wmode from transparent to opaque, and voila... everything works as expected. I have no idea why, but it works well  now...
Thanks for the advice!

Comment: You might need to show some code on how the images/MC's are being loaded

Comment: Pepper Flash strikes again!

Comment: I'm just using regular AS3 Loader class to load the images and then add them to the stage... The funny thing is that it's not consistent - sometimes it appears there and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry for my previous, not so helpful, comment... I guess I'm tired of informing everyone how buggy Pepper Flash is in Chrome. You might want to disable it at chrome://plugins -- you will have several Flash plugins installed, disable the one w/"PepperFlash" in the path. The problem will likely go away. Not a great solution, but it will at least confirm if Pepper Flash is the issue. You are not alone, do a search for Pepper Flash and revel in everyone else's pain with this new plugin that Chrome uses.